# determine mean value on 0Y histogram axis

Tags: r, histogram

I am drawing histograms using hist command as below:

```
hist(plikTVDI, ylab='częstość występowania',
     xlab=xetyk, col='red', main=etykieta, cex.lab=1.5)
```

Then I am adding tekst:

```
text(x=mean(plikTVDI,na.rm=TRUE),y=40,labels=tekst_srednia_l, cex=3, col='blue')
```

Is there any possibility to determine where is mean of y axis (it will be better then constant 40).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may not be understanding your question correctly, but I think you'd like to identify the midpoint of the y axis when you create a histogram?

If that's the case, if you store the results of `hist` in a variable, like so:

```
tmp <- hist(...)
```

you can access the count values that determine the heights of the bars via `tmp$counts`. So the midpoint of the y axis would be `tmp$counts / 2`.

Alternatively, if you wanted the *mean* of the heights of the bars, you could simply do:

```
mean(tmp$counts)
```

Comment: +1;So now that you have offer exactly the same answer as I was composing, how to get this interface to understand that I don't want to post?

Comment: @DWin [Tell](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68957/manually-clear-saved-question-drafts) me about it!

Comment: Thanks. I had formed the incorrect impression that a whole bunch of drafts were sitting out there in the SO cloud.